# How to make a calculator which shows all the operations on the calculator screen?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to make a calculator and i have learnt from many tutorials but what i want to achieve is to show the operations on the calculator screen ; something like " 2 + 3 * 4 / 7 mod 3 ". How can this be done ?

Comment: stop asking the same question over and over again. Several of them already have been answered. If the ans do not fulfil your needs or requirement, either 1) update your question to answer their doubt, 2) update your question to give them more information on your current method and technique used, 3) tell them what is missing/wrong with their code that it does not suit your proj and they will try to help you as closely as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read this [tutorial](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/) of stanford. The first demo of this class is a calculator, leading you to walk through the how precession. It's worth reading.

And this is the [iTunes U video link](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=395605774)

Answer (score 0):

What you do is keep a stack of the key presses you use to get to the point where you are, when the key is a number, calculate the answer and when you get a new key press, redraw your display view and render the values from the bottom of the stack.

There are quite a few apps like that on the store if you need inspiration.